# Send Devise E-mails using Mandrill in Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, devise, mandrill

I'm trying to send the Devise e-mails from my Rails 4 app. I don't want to change the templates or anything, I just want to use Mandrill to deliver the messages in the production environment.

My `production.rb` is like this:

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => 'sociedadeavalia.com.br'}
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp.mandrilapp.com",
    :port    => 587,
    :user_name => ENV['MANDRILL_USERNAME'],
    :password => ENV['MANDRILL_APIKEY'],
    :authentication => 'login',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :domain  => 'sociedadeavalia.com.br'
  }
```

I have this in my `devise.rb`

```
config.mailer_sender = 'no-reply@sociedadeavalia.com.br'
config.mailer = 'MyDeviseMailer'
```

And I created the following mailer:

```
class MyDeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer
  helper :application
  include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers
  default template_path: 'devise/mailer'  
end
```

Now Whenever i try to send an email in production (the confirmation email for creating a new user account) my app just crashes and this appears in the log:

```
31 <190>1 2014-12-03T22:17:07.987969+00:00 app web.1 - - Net::OpenTimeout (execution expired):
```

What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be having an issue with the port being blocked. We'd recommend the troubleshooting steps [here](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/24633717-Why-am-I-getting-a-Relay-Access-Denied-error-trying-to-send-through-SMTP-). More specifically, try changing the port you're using - 2525 is often not blocked, or use 465 with SSL enabled. Many hosts block 25 and 587 to help prevent spam.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the authentication to 'plain'.  That is what is working for me.

```
:authentication => 'plain',
```

Comment: Perhaps you have some IP restrictions in place b/n your web server and mandrill?

Comment: I don't know. But I tried sending an email from the Mandrill Dashboard to the same address I was using in the app and it worked. Works in the dash board but not in the app.